# bash is not terminating

Tags: bash

I'm trying some things with my shell.
This includes the following command:

`kill $$`

My expectation was that the shell would log me out and terminate itself.
But instead the bash persists without change.

Any idea why? 
I ran this command on different environments (archlinux, debian). The behavior was always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found some statement:

> When bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores SIGTERM (so that kill 0 does not kill an interactive shell), and SIGINT is  caught
>          and  handled  (so  that the wait builtin is interruptible).  In all cases, bash ignores SIGQUIT.  If job control is in effect, bash ignores SIGTTIN,
>          SIGTTOU, and SIGTSTP

So that fact that I have a interactive shell simple let the `bash` ignore the signal.

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score -2):

The shell catches many signals and this applies to `SIGTERM` as well, which is the default signal send by `kill`.

If you really like to terminate the shell via `kill`, use `kill -KILL $$`.